# Does a process only have one "effective group id" associated with it?

Tags: linux, permissions, process

Each process has three user IDs:

- Real user ID (`ruid`).
- Effective user ID (`euid`).
- Saved user ID (`suid`).

Similarly, a process has three group IDs:

- Real group ID (`rgid`).
- Effective group ID (`egid`).
- Saved group ID (`sgid`).

Based on my understanding, the `euid` is used when accessing a file to match it with the owner of the file.

But I am not sure about the `egid`. Is the `egid` also used when accessing a file to match it with the group of the file? If so, then shouldn't each process have many effective groups IDs since each user can belong to many groups?

Answer (score 3):

There is one `egid`. However! At least in BSDlandia (and copied by Linux; not sure what SysV does here) there is the [`setgroups(2)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man2/setgroups.2) call

```
DESCRIPTION
     setgroups() sets the group access list of the current user process
     according to the array gidset.  The parameter ngroups indicates the
     number of entries in the array and must be no more than {NGROUPS_MAX}.

     Only the superuser may set new groups.
```

and `getgroups(2)` to retrieve that list.

Some programs notably *drop* the supplemental group list e.g. `httpd` on OpenBSD in `src/usr.sbin/httpd/proc.c`

```
    if (setgroups(1, &pw->pw_gid) ||
        setresgid(pw->pw_gid, pw->pw_gid, pw->pw_gid) ||
        setresuid(pw->pw_uid, pw->pw_uid, pw->pw_uid))
            fatal("%s: cannot drop privileges", __func__);
```

which may be surprising if you were expecting those supplemental groups to be around.

`NGROUPS_MAX` is another fun limit, especially involving NFS and folks in lots of groups, though there are now ways around that (besides the old way of not adding a user to more than the typical 16 groups).